# How to make working variadic arguments method inheritance with same method overloaded on child class

Tags: c++, inheritance, variadic-functions

Following code works:

```
class Test_Interface {
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    void Split(int weight, Args... args){
        Split(weight);
        Split(args...);
    }

    virtual void Split(int weight) {
        std::cout << "Test_Interface::Split weight: " << weight << std::endl;
    };
};

class Test : public Test_Interface {};

int main()
{
    Test test;
    test.Split(1, 20, 300);
}
```

But if I define overload for method *Split* in *Test* class like:

```
class Test : public Test_Interface {
public:
    virtual void Split(int weight) {
        std::cout << "Test::Split weight: " << weight << std::endl;
    };
};
```

Then I get error like: *error: no matching function for call to 'Test::Split(int, int, int)'*

I know that if I also define variadic arguments method in class *Test* like:

```
class Test : public Test_Interface {
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    void Split(int weight, Args... args){
        Split(weight);
        Split(args...);
    }

    virtual void Split(int weight) {
        std::cout << "Test::Split weight: " << weight << std::endl;
    };
};
```

It work again but then it doesn't do what was intendend in the first place, which is having only one place (interface) where is defined variadic arguments method and having each derived class only with custom implementation of non-variadic method. My goal is to avoid copy-pasting same code over and over again and maintain it on multiple places. Why when child class do not overload the method inheritance work ? Is there a way to do it without copy-pasting ? Thank you

Comment: Note that the problem is not at all related to variadic templates. See, e.g.: https://wandbox.org/permlink/RlmOGw27cghoubxB.

Comment: @DanielLangr good point, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare the `Test::Split` function, you *hide* the inherited functions. After that, when you use `Split` on a `Test` object, then the compiler only knows about `Test::Split` and not the parents `Test_Interface::Split` functions.

The solution is quite easy: You pull in the symbols from the parent class into the `Test` class:

```
class Test : public Test_Interface {
public:
    using Test_Interface::Split;  // Pull in the Split symbol from the parent class

    virtual void Split(int weight) {
        std::cout << "Test::Split weight: " << weight << std::endl;
    };
};
```